# How to load images through webpack when using HTMLWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using HTMLWebpackPlugin and in my template I have an img tag:

```
<img src="./images/logo/png">
```

If you notice, here I am using a relative path thinking webpack will trigger the file loader that's configured in my webpack.config.js file but after compilation I get the exact same src attribute in my html:

```
<img src="./images/logo/png">
```

How can I trigger webpack to dynamically replace these relative paths with, well whatever I've configured in my webpack configuration?

Answer (score 42):

I'm not a webpack expert, but i got it to work by doing this:

```
<img src="<%=require('./src/assets/logo.png')%>">
```

Plugin config

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: 'index.html'
  }),
```

According to the docs: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md

> By default (if you don't specify any loader in any way) a fallback
>   lodash loader kicks in.

The `<%= %>` signifies a lodash template

> Under the hood it is using a webpack child compilation which inherits
>   all loaders from your main configuration.

Calling `require` on your img path will then call the file loader.

You may run into some path issues, but it should work.

Comment: I got it to working like this, too. But the problem is I **am** using a custom loader. To be specific I am using handlebars. And it doesn't seem to support direct function calls inside templates. And secondly it looks pretty messy. I'd hate do it over and over again. I have dozens of html pages with lots of images in it.

Comment: Upvoted, but it bums me out that there's not an easy way to get non-required image sources playing nicely with this plugin.

Comment: Result: `src="[object Module]"`

Comment: @arthur src="[object module]" is resolved by setting  esModule: false in the rule.options section of the loader. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687448/2784280.

Answer (score 32):

Using html-loader with HTML webpack plugin worked for me.

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
         test: /\.(html)$/,
         use: ['html-loader']
      }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ]
```

Comment: Hi Norma, I followed your advice, but it seems this is not enough. I get error "appropriate loader is needed". So you should have used something else apart from htmlwebpackplugin and html-loader

Comment: @Denis Yes, you'll need an additional loader depending on the file type. Check out https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/ for some examples.

Comment: This worked as far as it allowed WebPack to pick up (import) the images from HTML <img> tags without the use of require statements, but it prevented _lodash <%= %> being interpreted by HTMLWebpackPlugin (leaving the text untranslated) and I couldn't find a fix for that. See https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/223

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I suppose if I was using lodash expressions (`<%=%>`) then I'd have to choose which way to go, but until then, this is excellent

Comment: You may need to disable `esModule`: `use: [{ loader: 'html-loader', options: { esModule: false } }],`

Answer (score 12):

You should use the `CopyWebpackPlugin`.

`const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');`

```
plugins:[
    ....
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({'patterns': [
        { from: './src/assets/images', to: 'images' }
    ]}),
    ....
]
```

This is copy the `src/assets/images` to your `dist/folder/images`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use url-loader in your webpack config to add images below a certain limit encoded as base64 uri's in your final bundle and images above the limit as regular image tags (relative to the publicPath)

```
module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{ 
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      publicPath: "/"
    }
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while following the Getting Started guide that Webpack provides. I was using the template code from the guide and bundling images. But then when migrating an existing vanilla html/js/css project to use Webpack, I discovered that in order to use the template HTML loading like I wanted -- with paths to image resource contained in the template -- I had to remove the asset loader usage from my `webpack.config.js` for the `html-loader` to properly resolve the new hashed paths it was creating in `dist`

To use Webpack doc syntax, remove the lines prefixed with "-" and add the lines prefixed with "+"

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      - test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
      - type: 'asset/resource',
      + test: /\.(html)$/,
      + use: ['html-loader'],
    }
  ]
}
```