# How to use html-loader with webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack

What should I type in `<img>` 'src' attribute to make html-loader replace it with URL? Assume folder 'public' is served via webpack-dev-server, project layout looks like

```
- src
  - index.js 
- img
  - dog.jpg
  - cat.jpg
- public
  - index.html
```

webpack.config.js has rules for url-loader and html-loader:

```
{ test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
{ test: /\.(html)$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
```

index.js imports images:

```
import './../img/cat.jpg'
import './../img/dog.jpg'
```

And index.html has `<script>` for index.bundle.js. I expect `<img src="dog.jpg">` to be processed, but this doesn't happen. Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The question is answered here. It should be closed now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126503/how-to-load-images-through-webpack-when-using-htmlwebpackplugin

Answer (score 0):

By default every local  is required (require('./image.png')). You may need to specify loaders for images in your configuration. I would highly recommend you to use file-loader or url-loader in this scenario in place of html-loader. Infact on html-loader's github documentation only suggest this.